# Not understanding scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I don't quite understand this bit of code.

```
$('div').click((function () { 
    var number = 0;
    return function () {
        alert(++number);
    };
})());
```

My understanding is:

- An anonymous function is defined and assigned to the click handler.
- When I click on div, this function is invoked.

What the function does is:

- Define a variable `number` = 0
- Return `++number`

So why does the number in alert increment every time I click? Shouldn't `number` be reset to 0 every time I click?

Comment: The function is not invoked when you click the div. The function is invoked immediately. Look up IIFE.

Comment: So `number` lives in the scope of the outer function, which the inner function has access to. Every time I click, the inner function gets invoked (cuz it's the "return value"). On the other hand, the outer function is invoked immediately. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you've got a *self-invoking function*, which returns a function. Watch out for the brackets at the end:

```
(function () { 
    var number = 0;
    return function () {
        alert(++number);
    };
})()
```

So **the callback of the click handler is only the returned inner function**:

```
function () {
    alert(++number);
};
```

**This inner function has access to the variable `number`**, which is in the scope of the outer function.

So your code can also be written as follows:

```
function outerFunction() {
    var number = 0;
    return function () {
        alert(++number);
    };
};

var innerFunction = outerFunction();

$('div').click(innerFunction);
```

Comment: So, the thing that happens when I click is not all the stuff within `click()`, but only the stuff that gets returned within `click()`?

Comment: I've added an other way of implementing your click action. This should clear things up.

Answer (score 2):

If we used (ugly) names for the anonymous functions, your code could be rewritten as:

```
$('div').click((function makeIncrementer() {
    var number = 0;
    return function incrementAndAlert() {
        alert(++number);
    };
})());
```

More verbose code retaining similar semantics would be:

```
var makeIncrementer = function() {
    var number = 0;
    return function() { alert(++number); };
};

var incrementAndAlert = makeIncrementer(); // function() { alert(++number); }

$('div').click(incrementAndAlert);
```

`makeIncrementer` is a function that, when called, defines a `number` variable in its scope, and returns a function - note that `makeIncrementer` doesn't increment, nor alert the `number` variable, instead it returns another function that does just that.

Now `incrementAndAlert` is bound to this returned function

```
function() { alert(++number); }
```

that captures `makeIncrementer`'s `number` variable, which enables it to keep `number`'s state between `incrementAndAlert` calls triggered by `$('div')` clicks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an "answer", but hopefully it will show a different way of looking at the problem.

---

First off, note that JavaScript functions are *just* objects and are thus *just* values that can be bound to variables. As such,

```
$('div').click((function () { 
    var number = 0;
    return function () {
        alert(++number);
    };
})());
```

can be, with a simple expression substitution, rewritten as

```
var f = function () { 
    var number = 0;
    return function () {
        alert(++number);
    };
};
// $('div').click((f)()); and when removing extra parenthesis ->
$('div').click(f());
```

Then, after one more simple expression substitution

```
var g = f()
$('div').click(g);
```

it should be clear that the (outer) function, `f`, is invoked first and it is the resulting (inner function) value, `g`, that is used as the handler.

Aside from introducing variables, the above substitutions are semantically equivalent to the original code.

Comment: When I write `click(function() {$("body").remove()})` is there anything being "returned"? The removing action is being returned/attached to the click handler?

Comment: @Anh Break it down with equivalent expression substitution: `f = function() {$("body").remove()}; click(f)`. Note that `f` was *not* invoked in this case and thus is itself (a function) used as the handler.

Comment: So does `f` return anything? I still don't understand what is and is not assigned to the click handler. Is it the stuff that's inside `click()` or the returning value of that stuff?

Comment: In the shown substitutions, `f` is a function bound to a variable. A function can *only* "return" something when it is called/invoked (as in the case of `f()`). In the original example, it returns `g` (another function) *when* `f` was invoked via `f()`. It is then `g` (the inner function/closure, which was the *result* of invoking `f`) that is then passed to `click` *without* being called/invoked. The expressions above should be trivial enough to follow keeping that in mind.

Comment: Anyhow, once those concepts understood - functions *are* values and a function *only* "returns" a value when it is invoked - then it's just one step forward to understanding closures and variable scoping: Each new function *invocation* creates a new scope or "execution context", which is then bound in the resulting *closure* created when a [new] inner function (`g`) is returned from an *invoked* outer function (`f`).